# I want to click anywhere on the chat notification bar to remove it

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications, top-bar

When I see a chat notification bar, I want it to go away, so I click on it without thinking. Then I remember. It says:

> click here to remove the notification bar

And I have to click in that area to remove the bar. It would be so much more convenient to be able to click anywhere on the bar (except of course on links if there are any) to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

This could actually be frustrating.

If you accidentally click just slightly outside the link text, it would close the notification bar and you'd lose access to the link, so you wouldn't be able to click again in the proper location.  I'm not sure about everyone else, but I'm not always precise enough with a mouse, so I could see myself being frustrated by this change if it went through.

I think it's a fairly minor thing either way, but I'd prefer for it to remain the way it is.